# How to discard decimal numbers?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to solve the following task:

ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

To which I found this code to solve it:

```
    function validatePIN (pin) {
   if(pin.length === 4 && pin >= 0 || pin.length === 6 && pin >= 0){
   return true; 
 }

 return false;
}
```

EXCEPT this is the only task it is not passing:

Wrong output for '.234' - Expected: false, instead got: true :(

I have try to implement and if statement with a condition of `Number.isInterger(pin)` with no success :(

And I am out of ideas... I thought when you wrote `>= 0` it automatically eliminated decimals

Comment: Why did `Number.isInterger(pin)` not work?

Comment: I think there is a typo: `Number.isInteger(pin)` instead of `Number.isInterger`.

Answer (score 3):

How about using regex:

```js
    var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]{4}$'); 
    var yourPIN = "0001";
    console.log(reg.test(yourPIN));
    yourPIN = "1325";
    console.log(reg.test(yourPIN));
      yourPIN = ".325";
    console.log(reg.test(yourPIN));
```

Comment: Oh haha, that´s what I did. Thank you

Comment: Why not use `\d` and why not use the literal regular expression form?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of @Dalorzo. You can even shorten the regex up using `/.../`:

```js
// Should be true
let result = /^\d{4}$/.test('0000');
console.log(result);

// Should be false
result = /^\d{4}$/.test('.000');
console.log(result);
```

Here is also a nice documentation about Regex from the mozilla dev page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I don´t know if I am wrong but I solved it with a regex

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
   if(pin.length === 4 && pin >= 0 || pin.length === 6 && pin >= 0){
     if(pin.match(/[.+-]/)){
      return false
      } 

      else{
      return true; 
      }
 }

 return false;
}
```

Comment: Careful: `"    " >= 0` (four spaces) returns true!

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

```
if(pin == Math.round(pin) && (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6))
```

Comment: This returns true for `"    "` (a string of four spaces).

Answer (score -1):

One solution can be to check if the passed value is integer 
This checks for integer value

```
Number.isInteger(Number(pin))
```

If the value is not integer it will return false.

Based on this the completed function will be as follows :

```
function validatePIN (pinValue) {
let pin = pinValue.trim(); //to handle empty values, spaces 
 if(!Number.isInteger(Number(pin))){
    return false ;
 }  
 if(pin.length === 4 && Number(pin) >= 0 || pin.length === 6 && Number(pin) >= 0){
   return true; 
 }

 return false;
}
```

Also for positive value check `Number(pin) >= 0` is used.

Comment: This will return true for `"    "` (a string with four spaces) because 1) `"    ".length` is `4` and `Number("    ")` is `0`. If you need to check whether a string contains only numbers you really should be considering a regular expression.

Comment: @customcommander Agreed with the regular expression solution. In this case trimming the parameter will handle the case for empty strings..